# How to extend a column vector to a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

For a vector `a = [1 2 3]'`, I want to extend it to matrix `[1:1+n;2:2+n;3:3+n]`. Just like extend a number `x` to a sequential vector by `x:x+a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to add `0:n` to each element in `a`

```
b = bsxfun(@plus, a, 0:n)
```

Or if you're using MATLAB R2016b, you can replace the `bsxfun` approach with the following thanks to automatic broadcasting of dimensions.

```
b = a + 0:n
```

Comment: For the `linspace` solution, does it only work on 2015a and newer version? My current version is 2014a, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I should use the `bsxfun` solution

Comment: @BsHe Sorry, I was testing on Octave and forgot that MATLAB couldn't do that. The `bsxfun` solution is going to be faster regardless

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.